# PHP on Azure App Service slow performance when connected to Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-database-mysql

I am hosting a PHP 7.2 website written on CodeIgniter 3 framework on Linux Azure App Service (plan P1v2). The database is MySQL 5.7 running on Azure Database for MySQL (General Purpose, 2vCores, 5GB storage) with SSL disabled.

When I browse my website, it literally takes about 8-9 seconds to load where browser would stay the white page and display everything at once after finished loading. (most of website contents are pulled from database)

I have been monitoring both App Service and MySQL DB and the average %CPU have never reached 50% of their allocated resource, so the specs does not seem to be the problem.

My outsourced developer team has their own testing environment (not on Azure) and they said it loads almost instantly on their environment, so they are blaming Azure.

I then noticed that Azure Advisor was telling me two things about this database where the impact is High

> **Improve MySQL connection latency**
> Our internal telemetry indicates that your application connecting to MySQL server may not be managing connections efficiently. This may result in higher application latency. To improve connection latency, we recommend that you enable connection redirection. This can be done by enabling the connection redirection feature of the PHP driver.

> **Improve MySQL connection management**
> Our internal telemetry indicates that your application connecting to MySQL server may not be managing connections efficiently. This may result in unnecessary resource consumption and overall higher application latency. To improve connection management, we recommend that you reduce the number of short-lived connections and eliminate unnecessary idle connections. This can be done by configuring a server side connection-pooler, such as ProxySQL.

I am now working on enabling the connection redirection to reduce latency but still not successful as I am not familiar with CodeIgniter so I need to wait for the developers to fix it.

My question is: what is/are the cause(s) of this performance issue? Are those two recommendations really the causes of this problem?

Both App Service and database are in the same region. Do they communicate locally like some kind of LAN connection? I hope the connection from App Service would not go out through the internet then back to Azure DB, causing slow performance.

Thanks.

Comment: It's very difficult without code to be able to answer this.  It sounds like something is making more connections than it probably needs - and each connection is a reasonable delay.

Comment: The problem with this question is that without access to your environment, it is impossible to answer it objectively!

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: no it does not go out and come back in to make a connection to your DB, and Yes it is a connection issue but can you please share metrics screenshot for both the App Service and The Azure MySQL like CPU, Memory, IOPS and Throughput. Please share both average and max metrics. Connection metrics from the Metrics option your blade would be useful as well. Try to contact support from the top right in Azure Portal, using the question mark icon.

Answer (score 9):

I have fixed this issue, turns out the Azure Advisor was right! I have enabled connection redirection and now my website finishes loading in 3 seconds. Here are the what I did.

TL;DR Configure your app to use SSL when connecting to database and also put the `mysqlnd_azure` extension file in your deployed app, set Azure Web App's App Settings to read the ini file that make it loads the extension. Then set Azure MySQL DB server parameter `redirect_enabled` to ON and enable Enforce SSL with TLS 1.2. Restart the app.

Beware: Make sure that setting Enforce SSL is the last thing you do, otherwise it will reject all non-SSL connections and your app wouldn't work at all.

---

#### Update Jan 2021

I have just found out that it seems like Microsoft has already built-in the required `mysqlnd_azure` extension to Azure App Service. The majority of steps below are not required anymore.

You should first test if the extension has already been loaded by following step 7. If `mysqlnd_azure` extension is on the list then you can continue to step 8-10. You still need to follow step 1. to configure SSL certificate for your database though.

Afterwards, confirm if the database connection redirection is in use by following the sample code link in the reference at the end of this answer. You should see the text `mysqlnd_azure.enableRedirect: preferred`, followed by text in this format: `[random text and numbers].[random text and numbers again].[your azure region].worker.database.windows.net`.

If the text still shows your MySQL hostname you used, e.g. `mydatabase.mysql.database.azure.com`, then connection redirection is not in use. Check again.

Original answer below this line.

---

1. Configure your app to use SSL when connecting to database. In CodeIgniter, it's the `database.php` file in `/application/config/`. Make sure all MySQL drivers that you use have SSL enabled. Download the SSL certificate from https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem and store it in your app's directory e.g. `/cert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem`

   ```
    /*Snippet from database.php*/
    $db['production'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => getenv("DB_HOST"),
        'username' => getenv("DB_USER"),
        'password' => getenv("DB_PWD"),
        'database' => getenv("DB_NAME"),
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => FALSE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => [
            'ssl_key'    => NULL,
            'ssl_cert'   => NULL,
            'ssl_ca'     => '/home/site/wwwroot/cert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem',
            'ssl_capath' => NULL,
            'ssl_cipher' => NULL,
            'ssl_verify' => FALSE
        ],
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );

    /*Snippet for PHP (PDO)*/
    <?php
    define('CONN_HOST', getenv("DB_HOST"));
    define('CONN_DATABASE', getenv("DB_NAME"));
    define('CONN_USER', getenv("DB_USER"));
    define('CONN_PASSWORD', getenv("DB_PWD"));
    define('CONN_OPTION', array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA          =>     '/home/site/wwwroot/cert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES utf8"
    ));
   ```
2. Install `mysqlnd_azure` extension by following this link https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-adding-php-extensions/ or if you just want the .so extension right away, download it from http://www.mediafire.com/file/g6mzeld0wnqedw0/mysqlnd_azure.so/file otherwise build it yourself from https://github.com/microsoft/mysqlnd_azure
3. Put `mysqlnd_azure.so` in your app's directory. E.g. `/bin/mysqlnd_azure.so` Then deploy your code to Azure
4. SSH into your App Service, create a directory in `/home/site` called `ini`. Create an .ini file with any name e.g. settings.ini
5. Use vi or nano to edit that ini file and paste these lines

   ```
   extension=/home/site/wwwroot/bin/mysqlnd_azure.so
   mysqlnd_azure.enableRedirect = on
   ```
6. Tell your app to load the `mysqlnd_azure` extension by adding an application settings called `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` with value `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini`
7. Azure will force restart your app after saving the app settings. After that you can check if the extension has been loaded by SSH again and run `php -m` to see all loaded extensions. If you see `mysqlnd_azure` in the list, you're on the right path! If not, this command should tell why it couldn't load that extension
8. On Azure Portal, navigate to your Azure MySQL DB and set server parameter `redirect_enabled` to ON
9. Under Connection Security, enable Enforce SSL connection and choose TLS 1.2
10. Restart the app again.

If you use `sslmode=verify-ca` or `sslmode=verify-full`, you need to switch to the new SSL certificate on October 26, 2020. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-certificate-rotation **Update:** Microsoft has extended the deadline for root certificate deprecation till February 15, 2021.

If you have any deployment slots, make sure to do step 4-7 for every slot.

References:

- Sample code to confirm if connection redirection is working https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-redirection#confirm-redirection
- App Service Linux - Update PHP Settings https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-update-php-settings/
- Configure SSL connectivity in your application to securely connect to Azure Database for MySQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (with the exception of CodeIgniter), I will carefully review everything you have indicated in the post, but I would like to contact you privately.

You can find my contact in my profile; I don't put it here because I don't know if it's allowed. Thank you for the valuable information. PHP is not in my stack and I've been struggling with this for a while. Better machines, better disks, web apps, VM's,... and the result is unfortunate compared to other environments outside Azure.

Comment: @HugoL.M I have updated my answer to reflect new findings. You can discuss here if you want to, it might benefit others as well. Glad that you find my answer helpful.

Comment: still valide in may ?

Comment: Hey I have done everything from point 4. (because like you mentioned earlier mysqlnd_azure.so already exists). But the Webapp is still very slow. Is there any way to check if the setting "mysqlnd_azure.enableRedirect=on" is applied?

Comment: can't see redirect_enabled

Comment: it looks like this method does not apply to new azure flexible server. Is redirection config still needed in that case ?