# Migration from AWS EC2 MySQL DB to a Azure MySQL Database resulted in a very poor slow performance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, azure-devops

We had a very small MySQL DB of 150MB, which was running very fast with AWS t2.large database as Self Hosted.

***H/W spec: Azure: 2vCPU, 10GB memory, AWS: 2 vCPU, 8GB Memory.***

However, the company decided to move the AWS DB to the Azure Managed MySQL, and keep the PHP application in the EC2 for now.

H/W both servers equal in fact Azure had 2GB extra memory, with both have vCPU = 2,

Once moved to the Azure we saw massive performance degradation,

Example: **In AWS ajax request took 15 sec, In Azure same ajax request takes 2.5 minutes.**

Azure MySQL DB - the average %CPU and % Memory have never reached 50% of their allocated resource,
so the specs do not seem to be the problem.

As per the question below
[PHP on Azure App Service slow performance when connected to Azure Database for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970567/php-on-azure-app-service-slow-performance-when-connected-to-azure-database-for-m)

We did turn the Azure MySQL DB server parameter **redirect_enabled** to **ON** and enabled Enforce SSL with TLS 1.2.

And installed the "mysqlnd_azure" extension as well, usinge

```
sudo pecl install mysqlnd_azure
```

As per this below link we check this has any effect on the connection but it seems hostname is the same with no change

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-redirection#confirm-redirection

***In the below "Test code" if redirection is set to ON it gives me a error "Connect error (2002):" If redirection set to off in the ini file, Test code goes to the else with same HOST name, which suggest that redirection is not working, However can see mysqlnd_azure extension is loaded and table names are shown correctly in the resultset***

```
<?php
$host = '<yourservername>.mysql.database.azure.com';
$username = '<yourusername>@<yourservername>';
$password = '<yourpassword>';
$db_name = 'testdb';
 echo "mysqlnd_azure.enableRedirect: ", ini_get("mysqlnd_azure.enableRedirect"), "\n";
 $db = mysqli_init();
 //The connection must be configured with SSL for redirection test
 $link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
 if (!$link) {
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
 }
 else {
   echo $db->host_info, "\n"; //if redirection succeeds, the host_info will differ from the hostname you used used to connect
   $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;'); //test query with the connection
   print_r ($res);
   $db->close();
 }
?>
```

Application is done with Code-igniter and PEAR.

**Does anyone have a similar experience when running Code Igniter with Azure MySQL DB with AWS EC2? and Any suggestions to fix this issue?**

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: Are you saying you went from having all resources hosted on AWS to application hosted on AWS and database on Azure? I.e. different data centres with associated latency increases - could that not be your issue?

Comment: Is the delay in the HTTP request-response, the MySQL connection, or the data retrieval from MySQL?

Comment: Let's see the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And how big is the resultset?  (It sounds like an I/O problem.)  What disk do you have -- HDD / SSD / NVMe / etc?

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @Dharman not sure where the dealy is request-response, the MySQL connection, or the data retrieval from MySQ, is there a way to findout how each one of them takes,,,Ajax request takes long as 2.5 minutes to show the response.

Comment: @RickJames, I dont think query is problem, because same query works fine in AWS hosted, We only move the DB to the Azure, php files hosted on the AWS still

Comment: @Matt Yea php files in AWS and DB in the Azure, Everything hosted on same zone like AU for AWS and AU for Azure, I doubt any network latency will be 2.5 minutes per request ... isnt it.

Comment: You can measure each time. If the application belongs to you and you have access to the source code then it shouldn't be a problem for you to profile the application

Comment: @RickJames "innodb_buffer_pool_size" is 2684354560

Answer (score 3):

Your most urgent problem is that **you do not know**.

So the very first thing to do is to know -- to investigate **where** exactly things go awry.

For example (but you'll need to do more than this):

```
function after($msg) {
    global $tsts;
    if (isset($tsts)) {
        $time = floor((microtime(true)-$tsts)*1000);
    } else {
        $time = 0;
    }
    print "{$msg}: {$time} ms\n";
    $tsts = microtime(true);
}
    
after("Start");
$db = mysqli_init();
after("mysqli_init");
after("FINISH");

$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
after("mysqli_real_connect");

$res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;'); //test query with the connection
after("query");
// MUCH BETTER: a call to *execute* the query, and a different call
// to *retrieve* results, and you time *both* operations! See below

$db->close();
after("close");
```

This will tell you exactly where the time goes during the call. You can for example modify the after() function so that it immediately returns unless the REMOTE_ADDR is your exact workstation, otherwise it will silently save its data in an array, and when $msg is "FINISH" it will dump the array to a file. This way, seeding after() calls everywhere in your code, you will be able to see where the time costs are.

(This is a very poor man's profiling; xdebug and kcachegrind would be much better and precise choices, but have more taxing requirements and we just want to have a quick look at things).

This will tell you for example:

- is the **connection** slow?
- is the **query** slow?
- is the **result retrieval** slow?
- is **formatting the results** slow? (unlikely but, hey, it happens: different JSON libraries and lo!, you're stuck)
- is **sending results** slow? (very unlikely, but Azure can be (mis)configured almost every which way. I have a machine that is *intentionally* slowed this way to allow debugging specific UI issues).
- etc.

If the problem is in the connection, you'll study protocols, firewalls, possible alternative connections, possibly moving the whole app into Azure and leave only a redirection stub in EC2, etc etc.

If the problem is the query you'll need to check memory, indexes, possible thrashing, possible MySQL misconfigurations.

If it is the transfer, experiment with protocol compression, or investigate connection bottlenecks, or negotiate a better connection policy with either Amazon or Azure. Nothing can avail you if you have a 57600 bps connection, you need to take the trouble to whoever supplies you the bandwidth.

Without detailed timing information, you're stumbling in the dark.

## Small steps

- Begin with connecting to a simple bespoke service set up on the Azure machine. You might turn off the database completely, and instead set up a web server on MySQL's port 3306. Then from EC2 you would ask for "https://azure.host/index.html" and time *that*. If the whole slowness appears there, then you know the problem can only be in the network.
- Then fire up a test database with a single table of one record. Again, if the slowness appears there, it can only be the MySQL **network** configuration.
- Add a large table and run a query that will perform a full table scan, and return nothing. This stresses the buffer pool and disk I/O.
- Return the large table, an increasing number of records. This will test weird networking and firewalling problems (I had a MTU mismatch partially "remediated" by a borked Mikrotik once, boy was *that* a mess to investigate) as well as low bandwidth problems. Here you can test with compression both on and off.
- Finally run the test with a complex query. A slowness here might indicate problems either in the mysqld.conf (compare it with the one on EC2) or even some silly gotcha like forgetting to transfer *indexes* or even triggers (don't laugh, I did it once. Still smarts).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able isolate the problem, By doing a experiment, If move the db to localhost (default my.cnf) in the Azure instance I dont see any delay at all, which suggest, issue lies on the Network or Misconfiguration of the Azure MySQL DB conf, any advise on that area?

Comment: You need to pinpoint it more closely. Is it the network, or the database? You can now run some easy service on the Azure machine that will answer immediately to the EC2 instance (an instance of Apache itself, maybe: a small web site with a "hello world" HTML), and time *that*. If it goes fast, then it is the database. If the slowness is the same as the DB, then the problem is all in the network connection/bandwidth. If mid-way, unfortunately, *both* have problems.

Comment: However, it is unlikely that a problem of this magnitude lies in the MySQL configuration - unless someone really wrecked it, or you ran the test with some very large query that might slow down for architectural reasons (which *is* a test you should run -- **later**).
At this stage, the problem is likely more fundamental -- **communication between Azure and EC2 is slow**. They are in the same region, you say, so -- are there firewall policies? Is there bandwidth capping for some reason? In a pinch, you should ask both Microsoft and Amazon support.

Comment: After looking at the slowlong and query performance in the Azure, I found that, there is no issue on DB level, After doing some profiling on the code-level, I found there is a select from a dbtable which has 13000 rows and then there is a while loop that go through the results once by one that in that loop again called db functions get more data, profiling shows that each row takes about 0.76ms, which is very minimal, however since it scan through 10000+ rows, there is a sum up delay of ~50s, is there a way we can solve this problem? latency between aws and azure isn't it?

Comment: will persistent db connection? or output buffering be a solution? is there a way to do output buffering on the mysql cnf?

Comment: @mahen3d this is very probably worth a new question (make sure to edit this one indicating there is a follow-up), since you're starting with a much clearer picture. Yes, there are several things that could be done; you should specify an example of the pseudo-code you have. I'd remove the PHP tags from here (they really didn't matter). If *this* answer worked so far, you can accept it.
The new question is also more generic and likely to attract wider attention: you're asking how to optimize the throughput of a nested select loop, which is more common than an AWS/Azure migration.